# How to find out the `size` where `girth` equals to 3.5

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to find out the`size` where`girth` equals to 3.5

```
let arr = [
  { size:4, girth:3},{size:5,girth:3.5},{size:6,girth:4}
]
let size = arr.filter(arr => { return arr.girth === 3.5} )
```

`[ { size: 5, girth: 3.5 } ]` . I am trying to get just the size

Comment: What if there's more than one entry with `girth: 3.5`?

Comment: What if there's no entries with `girth: 3.5`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.find` instead of `.filter`:

```js
let arr = [
  { size:4, girth:3},{size:5,girth:3.5},{size:6,girth:4}
]

const found = arr.find(({ girth }) => girth === 3.5);
if (found) {
  console.log(found.size);
}
```

(If you're sure that an item will be found, you can leave out the `if` test)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `find`

```js
let arr = [
  { size:4, girth:3},{size:5,girth:3.5},{size:6,girth:4}
]

let size = arr.find(e => e.girth === 3.5).size;

console.log(size);
```

OR

```js
let arr = [
  { size:4, girth:3},{size:5,girth:3.5},{size:6,girth:4}
];

const searchByGirth = (arr, girth) => (arr.find(e => e.girth === girth)||{size: 0}).size;

console.log(searchByGirth(arr, 3.5));
console.log(searchByGirth(arr, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`:

```js
const arr = [
  { size:4, girth:3},{size:5,girth:3.5},{size:6,girth:4}
]

const size = arr.find(({ girth }) => girth == 3.5).size;
console.log(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `forEach`

```js
let arr = [
  { size:4, girth:3},{size:5,girth:3.5},{size:6,girth:4}
]
let output;
arr.forEach(({size,girth}) =>{
  if(girth === 3.5){
    output = size
  }
} )

console.log(output)
```

If you just want to get the first matching elements size, you can use `findIndex`

```js
let arr = [{ size:4, girth:3},{size:5,girth:3.5},{size:6,girth:4}]

let index = arr.findIndex(({girth})=> girth === 3.5)

if(index !== -1){
  console.log(arr[index].size)
}
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but if OP wants only the first match, this will return the last. Either way, it will perform unnecessary iterations

Comment: @Phil no where in question it is mentioned, but will add method for that too

Comment: I know, that's why I asked the question above (on the question itself)

Comment: @Phil added method for first found only case too

Answer (score 0):

To cover all the bases, including if there is more than one match or no matches, you can reduce the array of items to an array of `size` properties matching your conditions

```js
let arr = [
  { size:4, girth:3},{size:5,girth:3.5},{size:6,girth:4},
  {size:9001,girth:3.5} // I added this one for the example, it's over 9000
]

let thosePeskyThreePointFives = arr.reduce((found, { size, girth }) =>
    (girth === 3.5 && found.push(size), found), [])
    
console.info(thosePeskyThreePointFives)
```

The `.length` property will tell you how many matched.

Answer (score 0):

if there's more than one entry with girth: 3.5

```js
const arr = [{ size:4, girth:3.5}, {size:5, girth:3.5}, {size:6, girth:4}]
const sizes = arr.filter(v => v.girth === 3.5 ).map(v => v.size)
```

Answer (score -1):

Bro just use a loop, to run through it and check what object has girth equal to 3.5.

This should do the trick man...